# Using limit() on contained model

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

## The Code

Say I have two models, named `Product` and `Image`, which are linked by `Product hasMany Image` and `Image belongsTo Product`.

Now, say I want to fetch all products with the first image each. I would use this code:

```
$this->Products->find('all')
    ->contain([
        'Images' => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->order('created ASC')
                ->limit(1);
        }
    ]);
```

Looks about right, right? Except now only **one** of the products contains an image, although actually each product contains at least one image (if queried without the limit).

## The resulting Queries

The problem seems to be with the limit, since this produces the following two queries (for example):

```
SELECT
    Products.id AS `Products__id`,
FROM
    products Products
```

and

```
SELECT
    Images.id AS `Images__id`,
    Images.product_id AS `Images__product_id`,
    Images.created AS `Images__created`
FROM
    images Images
WHERE
    Images.product_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY
    created ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Looking at the second query, it is quite obvious how this will always result in only one image.

## The Problem

However, I would have expected the Cake ORM to limit the images to 1 **per product** when I called `limit(1)`.

My question: Is this an error in how I use the ORM? If so, how **should** I limit the number of images to **one per image**?

Comment: For future reference: I ended up simply omitting the `limit()` and just use the first image in the array. All the answers, while working, seem like a workaround. The Cake ORM **always** uses a single query for contains, even if this is undesired (like when adding a limit to the query).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The cleanest way you can do this is by creating another association:

```
$this->hasOne('FirstImage', [
    'className' => 'Images',
    'foreignKey' => 'image_id',
    'strategy' => 'select',
    'sort' => ['FirstImage.created' => 'DESC'],
    'conditions' => function ($e, $query) {
        $query->limit(1);
        return [];
    }
])
```

Comment: but i am not getting the last row ,i am getting the first one .can you plz suggest more?

Comment: Thank you i got it .Its really working.
I would like to upvote you.

Comment: @sradha - how did you solve this? I'm unable to sort in the primary hasOne array and order does not work in the conditions query either. I can only seem to get first result.

Comment: @MiDri check i have posted the codes ,it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Check it ,this one is my code

```html
 $this->Orders->hasOne('Collections', [
                    'className' => 'Collections',
                    'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
                    'strategy' => 'select',
                    'conditions' => function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp, \Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                    $query->order(['Collections.id' => 'ASC']);
                    return [];
                                                                                                                         }
                    ]);


                    $Lists = $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->contain(['Collections'])->order(['Orders.due_date DESC']);
                    $this->set(compact('Lists'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you are limiting it to one image is that you want to have a defaulted image.  You might consider adding a `default` field in the image table and doing a Alias like this:

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'CoverImage' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'conditions' => array('CoverImage.default' => true),
    ),
```

It looks like you are using Cake v3 so you can just add the equivalent association as the above is a 2.x sample.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model definition we would do the following:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'ModelName' => [
        'limit' => 1,
        'order' => 'ModelName.field DESC'
    ],
];
```

as described in the docs: https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany