# CakePHP Entity contain without foreign key

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.0

I have an entity Villa, and I want this Entity to contain other Villas which have the same 'complex' (`Varchar(255)`).

```
class VillasTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('villas');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Complexs', [
            'className' => 'Villas',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'propertyName' => 'complexs',
            'conditions' => ['Complexs.complex' => 'Villas.complex']
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

I don't know if it's possible. I don't want to add a find in each function who need those entity. Also I would like to make a function in the Entity which uses this new field.
``

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: In cakePHP 3 , we can't use false for the foreign key :'(

Comment: Ah, on a second look, it's a `hasMany` association, right, they don't support disabling foreign keys, as the ORM wouldn't know how to collect the keys and stitch the results together.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it was missing a comparision for the primary key in order to avoid the main record to be included in the associated records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that using a `VARCHAR(255)` as a foreign key is probably highly inefficient and/or will require huge indices, I guess that generally an option that defines the foreign key of the other table would come in handy here, similar to `targetForeignKey` for `belongsToMany` associations. You may to want to **[suggest that as an enhancement](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues)**.

### Result formatters

Currently this doesn't seem to be possible out of the box using associations, so you'd probably have to select and inject the associated records yourself, for example in a result formatter.

```
$Villas
    ->find()
    ->formatResults(function($results) {
        /* @var $results \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|\Cake\Collection\Collection */

        // extract the custom foreign keys from the results
        $keys = array_unique($results->extract('complex')->toArray());

        // find the associated rows using the extracted foreign keys
        $villas = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Villas')
            ->find()
            ->where(['complex IN' => $keys])
            ->all();

        // inject the associated records into the results
        return $results->map(function ($row) use ($villas) {
            if (isset($row['complex'])) {
                // filters the associated records based on the custom foreign keys
                // and adds them to a property on the row/entity
                $row['complexs'] = $villas->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($row) {
                    return
                        $value['complex'] === $row['complex'] &&
                        $value['id'] !== $row['id'];
                })
                ->toArray(false);
            }
            return $row;
        });
    });
```

This would fetch the associated rows afterwards using the custom foreign keys, and inject the results, so that you'd end up with the associated records on the entities.

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**

There might be other options, like for example using a custom eager loader that collects the necessary keys, combined with a custom association class that uses the proper key for stitching the results together, see

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::_collectKeys()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.EagerLoader.html#__collectKeys)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Association\SelectableAssociationTrait::_resultInjector()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Association.SelectableAssociationTrait.html#__resultInjector)**