# Use hasOne relationship to select latest record in cakephp 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 model: Product and SellingProduct. SellingProduct store selling information as sold date, sold price. A product record has many selling product records.

I want to fetch latest selling product record of a product. I use hasOne but don't work.

```
$this->hasOne('LastSellingProduct', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'order' => ['LastSellingProduct.created' => 'DESC'],
        'limit' => 1,
        'propertyName' => 'last_selling_product',
        'className' => 'SellingProducts'
    ]);
```

Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading Associated Model Data in Cakephp3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/loading-associated-model-data-in-cakephp3)

Answer (score 0):

How about using virtual fields instead?

I would set

```
$this->virtualFields('LastSellingProduct','SELECT product_id from `selling_products` where id = (SELECT MAX(id) from `selling_products` WHERE product_id=Product.id)');
```

or from your products Model add a virtual field

```
public $virtualFields = array('LastSellingProduct'=>'(SELECT product_id FROM `selling_products` WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `selling_products` WHERE product_id=Product.id))');
```