# cakephp 3.x fetching latest 4 posts from each subcategory listed under parent category

Tags: cakephp, greatest-n-per-group, cakephp-3.0

Postcategories(tree structure) has many Posts. Now parent postcategories will have Postcategories.parent_id null.

```
$postcategories = TableRegistry::get('Postcategories',[
            'className' => 'App\Model\Table\PostcategoriesTable', 
            'table' => 'postcategories'
    ]);    
//I get $parents post categories whose parent_id is null and the bellow code is for finding latest 4 posts from each child for typical parent.

$childs = $postcategories->find('children',['for' => $parent['id'],
            'fields'=>['Postcategories.id','Postcategories.name']])->contain([
            'Posts'=>['strategy'=>'subquery','queryBuilder' =>function ($q) use ($parent){
                        return $q->select(['Posts.id', 'Posts.title','Posts.postcategory_id'])
                        ->order(['Posts.created'=> 'DESC'])                         
                        ->limit(4);}]])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

this piece of code fetches total of 4 posts from the database while I am trying to fetch 4 posts of each child category of the parent category. How can be done. I can post further code for more clarity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading Associated Model Data in Cakephp3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/loading-associated-model-data-in-cakephp3)

Comment: @ndm I didnt find solution yet for this query. I can explain more if needed but what you are suggesting is not similar to my query.