# how to only pick the first many-to-many record and have it as a separate relation?

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0

My Tables are as follows:

`EventTicketSales` belongsToMany `Approvings` via `EventTicketSalesApprovings`.

Inside `EventTicketSalesTable.php` I wrote

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Approvings', [
        'className' => 'Contacts',
        'joinTable' => 'event_ticket_sales_approvings',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'saveStrategy' => 'replace',
    ]);
```

When I do pagination, I write

```
$contain = [
        'Approvings'
    ];

$sales = $this->paginate($this->EventTicketSales->find()->where($conditions)->join($join)->contain($contain));
```

Inside the search.ctp, I write

```
 <?php foreach($eventTicketSales as $eventTicketSale):?>
    <tr>
         <td>
           <?= $eventTicketSale->approvings[0]->company ?>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

**What I would like is**

1. keep the many to many relationships between the contacts table and the `event_ticket_sales` table as Approvings relation,
2. but have a way to only query the first Approving only

**Why?**

The reason is this query I only need to show the first approving contact person in the page and still keep pagination.

and I want the query to be as efficient as I possibly can.

If there is a better way to do this with joins instead of contains, I will be happy to do so.

**What defines as first approving contact person?**

Suppose we have a `event_ticket_sales` that have 2 approvings. The one where the `id` in `event_ticket_sales_approvings` table is the smallest is the first one. Yes the `id` is primary integer auto increment.

**What are the conditions in the above pagination query?**

```
    $conditions = [
                'OR' => [
                    ['EventTicketSales.invoice_number LIKE' => '%'.$data['search_field'].'%'],
                    ['EventTicketSales.receipt_number LIKE' => '%'.$data['search_field'].'%'],
                    ['ApprovingsContacts.company LIKE'      => '%'.$data['search_field'].'%'],
                ]
            ];
```

**UPDATE**

I appreciate that there is a similar question here [How to limit contained associations per record/group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/loading-associated-model-data-in-cakephp3)

However, I want to state that:

1. that question is trying to find the Article and its highest scoring Abstract. therefore Article hasMany Abstract and Abstract belongsTo Article
2. In my case, the EventTicketSales belongsToMany Approvings via EventTicketSalesApprovings. Which is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/loading-associated-model-data-in-cakephp3

Comment: I agree it's similar but not exactly the same given that in that question the relationship is a one to many, whereas my question is more of a many to many.

Answer (score 0):

Se my approach for solve similar question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/104XcwVG6WI