# CakePHP 3 limit of association does not works

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

Below are the lines from cakephp documentation which does not work.

Changing Fetching Strategies

As you may know already, belongsTo and hasOne associations are loaded using a JOIN in the main finder query. While this improves query and fetching speed and allows for creating more expressive conditions when retrieving data, this may be a problem when you want to apply certain clauses to the finder query for the association, such as order() or limit().

For example, if you wanted to get the first comment of an article as an association:

```
$articles->hasOne('FirstComment', [
     'className' => 'Comments',
     'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
]);
```

In order to correctly fetch the data from this association, we will need to tell the query to use the select strategy, since we want order by a particular column:

```
$query = $articles->find()->contain([
    'FirstComment' => [
        'strategy' => 'select',
        'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
            return $q->order(['FirstComment.created' =>'ASC'])->limit(1);
        }
    ]
]);
```

THanks

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead. Please don't just dump Cookbook examples, show us _your_ associations, _your_ code, _your_ data, and describe your specific problem, even if you're trying to replicate a Cookbook example - thanks!

Comment: in my case there are many comments for a single article, now I need to know how to get latest comment for each article

Comment: That is what you should elaborate on in your question. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/how-to-limit-contained-associations-per-record-group**

Comment: I am not getting that can you customize according to my need thanks

Answer (score 2):

When working with `hasOne` note that CakePHP will strip the `ORDER BY` clause from the query after the `queryBuilder` is called. The `queryBuilder` is used to create the joining conditions for the `JOIN` clause. There is no SQL syntax that allows a `ORDER BY` clause inside an `ON (expression)` for a join.

You also have to use a SELECT strategy for `hasOne` if you want to use `ORDER BY`.

You can get around this issue by using a custom finder.

```
    $articles->hasOne('FirstComment', [
        'className' => 'Comments',
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'strategy' => Association::STRATEGY_SELECT,
        'finder' => 'firstComment'
    ]);
```

In your `CommentsTable` class define a custom finder which sets the order.

```
    public function findFirstComment($q) {
        return $q->order([$this->aliasField('created') =>'ASC']);
    }
```

CakePHP won't strip the `ORDER BY` clauses for `hasOne` when added by custom finders.

> Note: The custom finder has to be in the association's target, not the source table.

Comment: same time can you explain how to get three latest comments for each article

Comment: applying limit in query builder add a limit clause in 2nd query so this is not useful

Comment: adding a limit applies the limit to the entire query. So if there are 5 articles and if you want first comment of each article, you will only get only one comment in total.