# cakephp4 get 1st record from containing table with order by a field

Tags: orm, relationship, cakephp-4.x

I have cakephp4 project
having 1 to many relationship between `Portfolios` and `PSnaps`
I want to show all 'Portfolios' with one associated record from `PSnaps` where its `PSnaps.status=1` and `order=>['PSnap.order_at'=>'ASC']`

I tried many things but getting the correct result

below is giving 90% correct result only ordering on `PSnaps.order_at` is not working.

along with `hasmany()` i have created `hasOne()` association as shown in below model

`Model`

```
class PortfoliosTable extends Table
{ 
   public function initialize(array $config): void
   {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('portfolios');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasOne('FirstPSnaps', [
        'className' => 'PSnaps',
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
        'strategy' => 'select',//also tried join
        //'joinType'=>'LEFT',//also tried inner,left,right
        //'sort' => ['FirstPSnaps.order_at' => 'ASC'], //*******this is not working
        'conditions' => function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp, \Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
            $query->order(['FirstPSnaps.order_at' => 'ASC']);//*******also not working
            return [];
        } 
         
    ]) 
    ; 

    $this->hasMany('PSnaps', [
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
    ]); 
}
```

`Controller`

```
$pfolios = $this->Portfolios->find('all')
        ->select(['Portfolios.id','Portfolios.client','Portfolios.country','Portfolios.url'])
        ->where(['Portfolios.status'=>1])
        ->order(['Portfolios.order_at'=>'asc','Portfolios.id'=>'asc'])
        ->limit(8)
        ->contain([
            'FirstPSnaps'=>function($q){
                return $q
                    ->select(['FirstPSnaps.portfolio_id','FirstPSnaps.snap'])
                    //->where(['FirstPSnaps.status'=>1])
                    //->order(['FirstPSnaps.order_at'=>'asc'])
                    ;
            } 
        ])
        ->toArray();
```

it is returning correct porfolios with 1 p_snap record but ordering/sorting is not correct as I need first p_snap something like  `where p_snap.status=1 and p_span.portfolio_id= portfolios.id limit 1`.

Comment: You might be better off writing a dedicated query as part of the model, then just echoing out the first item in each of the return objects.

Comment: Check the `queryBuilder` capabilities in the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain).

Comment: I tried queryBuilder(), getting more errors

Comment: You need a little more trickery for that to work properly, using just sorting and loading all records, and then relying on the right record to be picked afterwards on PHP level, isn't overly advised, see **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/how-to-limit-contained-associations-per-record-group**. Also - shameless plug ahead - check out **https://github.com/icings/partitionable**, it's not stable yet, but you might find it useful and want to give it a try.