# CakePHP 4 - Query to find the latest status from another table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, groupwise-maximum

I'm using CakePHP 4 to build an application that shows an inventory of documents and the latest status for each document.

The tables are fairly simple:

- `documents`: This contains a list of documents, each of which has a unique `id`, a human-friendly name, a filename etc.
- `statuses`: This includes a list of about 10 different statuses that a document can go through within the application (e.g. "uploaded", "review requested", "reviewed", "rejected" etc). Each of these has a unique `id` and `name` (the name being the text of the status, such as "uploaded", "review requested" etc).
- `documents_statuses`: This is a history table that contains all of the statuses that a document has gone through. Any given document (`documents.id`) can appear multiple times in this table (using a foreign key of `documents_statuses.document_id` referring to the relevant `documents.id`). It also has a `documents_statuses.status_id` corresponding to a `statuses.id` in the statuses table mentioned above. Each row here has CakePHP's conventional `created` timestamp so we know when rows were inserted. This is enough to tell us dates/times about when the document got to a particular status.

What I'm trying to do is output a list of `documents` and show the **most recent** status from `documents_statuses` in my table. The HTML structure of the table is simple and contains 3 headings:

- Document Name
- Filename
- Last status

Writing a query to get the data for the first 2 columns is easy as the data for that belongs in the `documents` table:

```
// src/Controller/DocumentsController.php
public function index()
{
    $documents = $this->Documents->find();
    $documents = $documents->paginate($document);
    $this->set('documents', $documents);
}
```

In my template I can then reference `$documents->name` and `$documents->filename` to output the respective columns from the `documents` table.

I understand that I need some extra logic in this query which will `JOIN` to the `documents_statuses` table and then order the records in descending order with a `LIMIT` of 1 to get the most recent status per document. I know I also need to do a further `JOIN` such that `documents_statuses.status_id` returns the corresponding `statuses.name`.

I know that I can adapt my query to contain `documents_statuses` and `statuses`:

```
$documents = $this->Documents->contain(['DocumentsStatuses', 'Statuses'])->find();
```

But I don't know how to loop through the records in `documents_statuses` in this query and do the `->orderDesc->limit(1)` to get the most recent record. Furthermore I also know that to obtain the `statuses.name` I would need to get this query to join the `documents_statuses.status_id` and `statuses.id` to return `statuses.name` (e.g. "uploaded", "review requested" etc).

The application has been `bake`'d and the models associations are defined correctly.

Might something equivalent be described in the CakePHP docs?

#### Edit - Raw SQL

The following SQL is equivalent to what I'm trying to write using the ORM. The problem isn't particularly understanding the SQL involved, it's writing it using CakePHP's ORM syntax. Equally, if there is a "better" way to write this query I'm interested but the purpose of this question is how to make this work using CakePHP's [ORM](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html).

```
SELECT 
    documents.name, 
    documents_statuses.created, 
    statuses.name 
FROM documents
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT documents_id, MAX(created) AS created
        FROM documents_statuses
        GROUP BY documents_id
    ) recent_statuses
ON documents.id = recent_statuses.documents_id
LEFT JOIN documents_statuses
ON documents.id = documents_statuses.documents_id AND recent_statuses.created = documents_statuses.created
LEFT JOIN statuses
ON documents_statuses.status_id = statuses.id
```

Comment: You want to check **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/how-to-limit-contained-associations-per-record-group/30270675#30270675**.

Comment: Can a status revert?  That is, maybe a document is "approved", then regresses to "in review"?  Hence the _datetime_ in `document_statuses` is what determines "latest"?

Comment: Can CakePHP issue "raw" sql?  You seem to understand how to write the SQL, but Cake is getting in the way?

Comment: @RickJames yes, the statuses can regress. Whatever the most recent DATETIME (`documents_statuses.created` column with a foreign key of `documents_statuses.document_id` mapping to `documents.id`) is for each document (`documents.id`) is the appropriate record. It is a case of CakePHP getting in the way. I can write the SQL but cannot write it using Cake's ORM syntax.

Comment: @RickJames I've added the raw SQL to the question.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with a slightly complex `JOIN`; see the `[groupwise-max]` tag or my [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Alternatively, you could use a different schema pattern:

- `Current` -- this always has the latest 'status' (plus other info).  There would be one row per document.
- `History` -- essentially as you have it now.  But this is not looked at to find the "current status".  This table has many rows per document.

Your code would need to `INSERT INTO History` and `UPDATE Current` to update the `status`.  (Actually the Update could be a IODKU if you need to Insert when the row does not exist yet.)

The query in question would be simply `SELECT ... FROM Current ...` -- no Join needed.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer although the question is focusing on how to write this using CakePHP's ORM syntax (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html). The alternative approach is an interesting idea and one I'd not considered, arguably this would be easy to write in the ORM since it doesn't require any `JOIN`s. Upvoted for the info.

Comment: @Andy - I find that ORMs (etc) are designed for small datasets and fail to think much about scaling.  There are perhaps 100 such layers (Cake, Laravel, WP, Woo, etc) that try to hide the database from the user.  But, in general, they end up forcing the user to learn _two_ views of databases -- the layer's view and the underlying RDBMS view (aka "raw").

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer. Although it isn't specific to CakePHP it's better to understand the SQL involved. I also agree with Rick James that ORMs in general are too restrictive to do this kind of work. Indeed it might be the case nobody has answered how to do this in the ORM because it isn't actually possible. The link posted by @ndm as a comment on the question involves more code and is more convoluted than simply writing the "raw" SQL. Given that Cake has a means to execute raw queries this is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score -5):

```
$documents = $this->Documents->contain(['DocumentsStatuses'=>function(Query $q){ return $q->contain(['Statuses'])->orderDesc->limit(1);}])->find();
```

[book.cakephp.org](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)