# How can you create a 'hasOne' association based on a 'belongsToMany' one in CakePHP 4.4.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to create an association that I can use, where I get all the Courses of a particular Student, and another association which gives me the Course with the.. smallest average grade, let's say. Is it possible to do it in cake 4.4.x ?

I've tried to create a finder but I don't know how to access the parent entity attributes.

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/how-to-limit-contained-associations-per-record-group