# CakePHP 4.4: retrieve data that contains an association that matches an association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I need an indication, having not been able to find anything about it (but maybe it's my fault...). An indication also to the CakeBook will be fine.

In my application I have the `PatientsTable`. A `Patient` has many `Notes` and each `Note` belongs to a `NoteType`.

So something like this:

```
class PatientsTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        // ...

        $this->hasMany('Notes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class NotesTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        // ...

        $this->belongsTo('NotesTypes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'notes_type_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Patients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
```

```
class NotesTypesTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        // ...

        $this->hasMany('Notes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'notes_type_id',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, for each `Patient`, I would like to retrieve the last (using `limit(1)` and `orderDesc('date')`) `Note` for each `NoteType`.

I can also do a separate query to retrieve patient IDs if that is needed. It's not a problem.
And then, for each patient, run a new query (this would bring the total of queries to patients + 1, but that's fine with caching).

Right now I'm trying to retrieve this data for a single patient, **just to see if it works**.
As:

```
$noteTypes = $this->Notes->NotesTypes->find()
    ->contain('Notes', function (Query $Query): Query {
        return $Query
            ->matching('Patients', function (Query $Query): Query {
                return $Query->where(['Patients.id' => 35]);
            })
            ->orderDesc('date')
            ->limit(1);
    })
    ->all();
```

But it certainly doesn't work, so much so that the data I get like this doesn't even seem to make sense to me.

Do you have any suggestions or indications?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241975/how-to-limit-contained-associations-per-record-group might help? You could use something there to load patients, containing notes limited to one per type.

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt so this another duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775766/using-limit-on-contained-model because seems the problem is the `limit`

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a common problem which could be solved by saving in the patients table a nullable column "last_note_id" and when you are saving a note add in the "afterSave()" callback of NotesTable add 
if ($entity->isNew() && $entity->patient_id) {
                $this->Patients->updateAll(['last_note_id' => $entity->id], ['id' => $entity->patient_id]);
}
Then add a belongsTo('LastNotes', ['className' => 'Notes']) to retrieve the last entry by always using LastNotes instead of Notes

Comment: Thanks @wowDAS my problem is that each note belongs to a note type and I would need to retrieve the last note for each type (and for each patient).  but your idea is interesting and I thank you, perhaps with an ad hoc table it could be a solution

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is a common problem which could be solved by saving in the patients table a **nullable column "last_note_id"**

and when you are saving a note add in the "afterSave()" callback of NotesTable add

```
public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options) {
    if ($entity->isNew() && $entity->patient_id) {
        $this->Patients->updateAll(['last_note_id' => $entity->id], ['id' => $entity->patient_id]); 
    } 
}
```

Then add a

```
belongsTo('LastNotes', ['className' => 'Notes'])
```

to retrieve the last entry by always using LastNotes instead of Notes

Comment: Thanks @wowDAS my problem is that each note belongs to a note type and I would need to retrieve the last note for each type (and for each patient).  but your idea is interesting and I thank you, perhaps with an ad hoc table it could be a solution

Comment: However, now that I think about it, thanks to your suggestion, I could use the `afterSave()` method to cache the same thing, for example `last_note_type_3_patient_2`.  with long-term cache.  this might be ok